# How to convert .nii to .nii.gz file?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, gzip

I have lots of `.nii` file. I want to know how to convert `.nii` file to `.nii.gz` file?

Thanks

Comment: to convert? or to rename?

Comment: @MendiBarel, to convert!

Comment: `.gz` means gzip.... simply zip up the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is nothing special about zipping NIfTI files. In MATLAB, you could simply do:

```
gzip('niftifilename.nii') % this will return niftifilename.nii.gz
gzip('*.nii') % for multiple nii files to create one .nii.gz
```

To work with the file again, you can unzip it, using `gunzip`. I've tried this on my Mac (don't know if this will work on Windows).

Typically, they are volume data, and hence take up a fair bit of disk space. Zipping it is purely for reducing the size of the file, and should not modify data.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
gzip({'*.nii'},outputdir)
```

Which will zip all your nii files into a nii.gz and place it into outputdir.

From the documentation:

> To gzip all .m and .mat files in the current directory and store the
>   results in the directory archive, type:
>
> gzip({'*.m','*.mat'},'archive')